# Im not getting my selected value in pod 'DropDown'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods, dropdown

I have installed `pod 'DropDown'` in my project. When I press the button it shows the drop down with list of months when I select month from the list it should show in the place of button like every drop down works but I'm not able to get my selected value. Button space remains blank.

```
var dropDown = DropDown()

@IBAction func dropDownButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

    dropDown.anchorView = dropDownButton

    dropDown.dataSource = ["1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4"]
    dropDown.show()

    dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
        print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
    }

    dropDown.direction = .bottom

}
```

Comment: You should file a bug in that pod's repo.

Comment: @SShahid maybe im doing something wrong

Comment: please add code to question

Comment: @HarshalWani check it now

Answer (score 1):

You need to create `outlet` of `UIButton` or get button from method argument `sender` .

Below I've created outlet and in `dropDown.selectionAction` set button title upon selection.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

let dropDown = DropDown()
@IBOutlet weak var menuButton: UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    dropDown.anchorView = menuButton
    dropDown.dataSource = ["1","2","3","4","1","2","3","4"]

}

@IBAction func dropDownButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    dropDown.show()
    dropDown.selectionAction = { [unowned self] (index: Int, item: String) in
        print("Selected item: \(item) at index: \(index)")
        self.menuButton.setTitle(item,for: .normal)
    }
}
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: I have made an other solution by creating a label and pass the value of selected index
 self.dropDownLabel.text = self.dropDown.selectedItem